# JMeter recorder through a VPN

Tags: http, jmeter, automated-tests, vpn

JMeter Recording Controller is unable to record HTTP requests from a website that I'm connected to via a VPN

Even when I'm connected through the same proxy port on JMeter as the VPN

I couldn't find any guidance on how to handle this problem

Is this possible, or am I attempting something stupid

Comment: This might help: `jmeter.bat -H <your proxy address> -P <your proxy port number> -u <your vpn user name> -a <your vpn password>`